# Python Text searching does not match values

Tags: python, text-mining

Hello I've list of word to search in pandas dataframe. Once I execute my code it match only few of them for example 4 of 7 but there more about let's say 1000.
Here what I did.

```
stopwords = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('french')
ps = nltk.PorterStemmer()

def clean_text(text):
    text = "".join([word.lower() for word in text if word not in string.punctuation])
    tokens = re.split('\W+', text)
    text = " ".join([word for word in tokens if word not in stopwords])
    return text

ptf_dates['cleaned_nomComplet'] = ptf_dates['nomComplet'].apply(lambda x: clean_text(x))

# CodeNaf related to sport.
code = ["sport","circuit", "club ","federation", "team", "sportifs"]

ptf_dates["topNomClient"] = ptf_dates["cleaned_nomComplet"].str.lower().apply(lambda x: True if x in code
                                                                             else False)
ptf_dates.groupby("topClient").size()
ptf_dates.to_csv("../05Outputs/01data/csv_top_textClean.csv", encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

When I search "sport" keyword in excel on column "cleaned_nomComplet"  it return 175.
What's wrong with my code, why I can not match "sport"?
Thanks

Comment: Is that possible that the "sport" keyword you match in excel is something like `sport1` or `sport-whatever`, if that's the case then the issue is that you are looking for the for the exact `cleaned_nomComplet` to be in the `code` list, maybe trying to search each code INSIDE `cleaned_nomComplet` would do the trick (foreach code: is it in cleaned_nomComplet ?).

Comment: Yes in Excel it match sometimes word like "transport"  ... but without counting these. There is many word "sport" or "federation" but it found only few. Is there another way to search?

Comment: can you provide some data from `ptf_datesa`,  `head()`  ?

Comment: sorry it's confidential.

Comment: The column in which I'd like to lookup has only name and surname. It can be enterprise name or person name.

Comment: @abdoulsn Well, if we want to ignore the words like `transport` and only looking for exact matches then it should be good, maybe your data have some empty spaces before/after, try to `word.strip().lower()` in the cleaning function. P.S. You don't have to apply the `.lower()` on `ptf_dates["cleaned_nomComplet"]` since this column is built using already lowered strings thanks to your cleaning function.

Comment: thanks
I tried out this kind of space carre but it give same result. I've found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50847430/8333806) it's working I'm checking validity.